# PHP links are not working

Tags: php, html, anchor, href

I just got started with PHP to build my website. Everything was fine, untile I tried to use my navbar. This is what it looks like:

This is `navbar.php` which gets included into `index.php`.

```
<div class="nav-items">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="biography.php">Biography</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.php">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="concerts.php">Concerts</a></li>
        <li><a href="booking.php">Booking</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click a link in my navbar, it doesn't direct me to the page. It's the same behavior as when you'd write `href="#"`. I just stay on the page, the URL doesn't change.

When I hover over the links, the path I see is correct. And when I manually type in that path, it works perfectly, the page gets rendered.

My file structure:

- css folder
- js folder
- templates folder

  - `navbar.php`
  - `footer.php`
- `index.php`
- `biography.php`
- `music.php`
- `pictures.php`
- `concerts.php`
- `booking.php`

I'm using XAMPP to run the site locally. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @syck I've now found out that a part of my jQuery code was responsible. It was code I used to display the active page:

```
$(function() {
    $('.navbar').on('click', 'div.nav-items ul li a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.navbar').find('.active').removeClass('active').end().end().addClass('active');
        $(activeTab).show();
    });
});
```

Once this code is removed, navigation works like a charm. Anyone know why it would cause this behavior?

Comment: I've googled for this, and found similar issues, but the solutions provided didn't work for me.

Comment: Try again with deactivating JavaScript and CSS includes before.

Comment: is your file structure in the htdocs folder? also the url for viewing the file in a browser when using xammp needs to be http://localhost/xampp/folder/filename.php

Comment: @gavgrif File structure is in the htdocs folder. The urls are correct, as they work when typed in manually.

Comment: @syck unfortunately, no difference...

Comment: @syck Sorry looks like I was to quick to dismiss your answer. I removed a small piece of jQuery code from my js file that showed the active page in nav. Now my navigation works.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <div class="nav-items">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="../biography.php">Biography</a></li>
     <li><a href="../music.php">Music</a></li>
     <li><a href="../pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>
     <li><a href="../concerts.php">Concerts</a></li>
     <li><a href="../booking.php">Booking</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="nav-items">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../biography.php">Biography</a></li>
        <li><a href="../music.php">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="../pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="../concerts.php">Concerts</a></li>
        <li><a href="../booking.php">Booking</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried it that way, it's not working for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<base href="your website" >
```

element in index.php

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some error with the path u have given..
give the correct path. check whether biography.php is found in the same location where the index.php is found.

Comment: The path is correct: when I type the url manually, it works. And I can see in the link preview in Firefox that it's the same url.